Spring Quartz : Triggers get deleted automatically when application restarts
I have configured spring-quartz in my application it works. Schedule a job register triggers with and works fine.
Every time it restart, all the existing triggers from table get deleted but not the jobs
this my quartz configuration
spring.quartz:
  initialize-schema: never
  job-store-type: jdbc
  properties:
    org.quartz:
      jobStore:
        class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
        driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate #(for fully JDBC-compliant drivers)
        isClustered: true #if you are having multiple instances of Quartz use the same set of database tables
        dataSource : quartzDataSource
      dataSource:
        quartzDataSource.driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        quartzDataSource.URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
        quartzDataSource.user: root
        quartzDataSource.password: admin
        quartzDataSource.maxConnections: 30

This is the error im getting
Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.class]: Could not initialize DataSource: quartzDataSource",

